# Calculate the closest colourblind-friendly colour?

Tags: php, python, algorithm, colors, accessibility

How can I calculate the closest colourblind-friendly colour from a HEX colour code like #0a87af or from the three RGB values (0-255).

I'm searching for an efficient way to calculate or do this so I can implement it in PHP or Python and the algorithm can be used for better website accessibility for colourblind people.

Comment: for a start there is more than one kind of 'colour-blind'. then converting a single colour is no good, it will always depend on at least 2 (foreground\background)

Comment: Also one question you should ask is "What is a colourblind-friendly colour?" Any individual colour can be colourblind-friendly, but if you combine that colour with another colour that clashes, it suddenly would become non-friendly. Have a look here for a grid with some colours and how they look in the different versions of colourblindness: http://safecolours.rigdenage.com/colours2.html

Comment: So a second parameter, background colour should be added I suppose. Would colourblind friendly mean "always the opposite colour of the background"? I hope not. Thanks @NicRobertson that's a helpful list.

Comment: Well your best option would probably be to choose colours from that list that match well in all spectrums or search for some good colourblind friendly palettes. If you have photoshop you can simulate colour blind mode on your designs which can help you select a good palette. If you need to dynamically generate themes, then it will be a bit harder, but you can try to use grey/white/black to stop yourself generating a really visually bad theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the others mentionned in their comments/answer, the contrast between two colours will be of importance.

The W3 already created a method defining a minimum contrast between colours in order to pass dfferent levels of accessibility.

They provide the description [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html) and the formula to calculate it is on the same page, at the bottom, [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html#key-terms) :

```
contrast ratio = (L1 + 0.05) / (L2 + 0.05)
```

For this apparently simple formula, you will need to calculate the relative luminance noted `L1` and `L2` of both colours using an other formula that you find [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#relativeluminancedef) :

```
L = 0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B where R, G and B are defined as:

if RsRGB <= 0.03928 then R = RsRGB/12.92 else R = ((RsRGB+0.055)/1.055) ^ 2.4

if GsRGB <= 0.03928 then G = GsRGB/12.92 else G = ((GsRGB+0.055)/1.055) ^ 2.4

if BsRGB <= 0.03928 then B = BsRGB/12.92 else B = ((BsRGB+0.055)/1.055) ^ 2.4
```

and RsRGB, GsRGB, and BsRGB are defined as:

```
RsRGB = R8bit/255

GsRGB = G8bit/255

BsRGB = B8bit/255
```

The minimum contrast ratio between text and background should be of 4.5:1 for level AA and 7:1 for level AAA. This still leaves room for creation of nice designs.

There is an example of [implementation in JS by Lea Verou](https://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/).

This won't give you the closest color as you asked, because on a unique background there will more than one front colour giving the same contrast result, but it's a standard way of calculating contrasts.

Answer (score 3):

A single color is not a problem for color-blind users (unless you want to transport a very specific meaning of that color tone); the difference between colors is.

Given two or more colors, you can convert them to HLS using [colorsys](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/colorsys.html) and check whether the difference in Lightness is sufficient. If the difference is too small, increase it, like this:

```
import colorsys
import re

def rgb2hex(r, g, b):
    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % (r, g, b)


def hex2rgb(hex_str):
    m = re.match(
        r'^\#?([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})$', hex_str)
    assert m
    return (int(m.group(1), 16), int(m.group(2), 16), int(m.group(3), 16))


def distinguish_hex(hex1, hex2, mindiff=50):
    """
    Make sure two colors (specified as hex codes) are sufficiently different.
    Returns the two colors (possibly changed). mindiff is the minimal
    difference in lightness.
    """

    rgb1 = hex2rgb(hex1)
    rgb2 = hex2rgb(hex2)

    hls1 = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(*rgb1)
    hls2 = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(*rgb2)

    l1 = hls1[1]
    l2 = hls2[1]

    if abs(l1 - l2) >= mindiff:  # ok already
        return (hex1, hex2)

    restdiff = abs(l1 - l2) - mindiff
    if l1 >= l2:
        l1 = min(255, l1 + restdiff / 2)
        l2 = max(0, l1 - mindiff)
        l1 = min(255, l2 + mindiff)
    else:
        l2 = min(255, l2 + restdiff / 2)
        l1 = max(0, l2 - mindiff)
        l2 = min(255, l1 + mindiff)

    hsl1 = (hls1[0], l1, hls1[2])
    hsl2 = (hls2[0], l2, hls2[2])

    rgb1 = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(*hsl1)
    rgb2 = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(*hsl2)

    return (rgb2hex(*rgb1), rgb2hex(*rgb2))


print(distinguish_hex('#ff0000', '#0000ff'))
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Contrast-Finder](http://contrast-finder.tanaguru.com/?lang=en)** is an open source online tool (written by Open-S and M. Faure) that, given foreground and background colors, will calculate the contrast ratio and if it's insufficient according to WCAG formula, will give you a bunch of background OR foreground colors with sufficient contrast ratio and thus options, using different algorithms (you must tell it if you want to keep the foreground color or the background color and if you want contrast ratio higher than 4.5:1 or 3:1 - level AA - or 7:1 / 4.5:1 - level AAA).
It's pretty spot on for many couples of colors.

**Sources** - in Java - are on GitHub.

Note: as already written in other answers, colourblind people ("people with colour deficiencies") are only a part of people concerned by the choice of colors: partially sighted people also are. And when a webdesigner chooses #AAA on #FFF, it's a problem for many people without any loss of sight or colour perception; they just've a shiny Retina® screen in non-optimal light conditions... :p